# Using Enum constant in switch with CodeModel

Tags: java, code-generation, sun-codemodel

I am using the [code model API](http://codemodel.java.net/) to generate java source files. I have an enum defined through codemodel API and I want to use that in a switch block. In a switch statement, the enum constants should be used as unqualified. I have trouble in accessing the unqualified name of the enum constants, as code model API qualifies the constants with the enum class name.

In short, I want to generate the following code fragment using codemodel APIs.

```
enum MyEnum {A,B};
MyEnum m = MyEnum.A;
switch (m){
   case A:
   //do something
   case B:
   //d0 something else
}
```

but codemodel generates like this

```
enum MyEnum {A,B};
MyEnum m = MyEnum.A;
switch (m){
    case MyEnum.A:
    //do something
    case MyEnum.B:
    //d0 something else
 }
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

`JExpr.ref("A")` gives a direct reference to the enum constant.